# Is it possible to edit Flash Pro CC 2015 HTML5 project JS code in an external editor a la AS2/3?

Tags: javascript, html, flash, ide, createjs

What the title says. I've always found external AS2/AS3 code IDE syntax and hilighting superior to the one built into Flash Pro, like SePy for AS2 and FlashDevelop for AS3.

For JavaScript, it's IDEs like Brackets, Sublime Text and Atom.

So my question is: is there a way to code Flash Pro HTML5 JavaScript externally, like with the AS2 #include directive to point to a .AS file or in AS3 by specifying .AS class files?

It's a bit of a pain to use Flash Pro's internal code IDE for JavaScript when I have superior IDEs installed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A barbaric method I use is to make a "frame_#.js" file, edit from there and then copy-paste the code from the external "frame_0.js" for example into frame 0 of the HTML5 .FLA, but as a workflow, it's a bit slow and not optimal.

Better ways would be appreciated!